# How can i make changes to this file Encoding?

Tags: windows, command-line, encoding, csv

**I have these 3 files**

```
21/08/2014  07:15 PM               122 Tw2AWK.csv
21/08/2014  07:15 PM               125 Tw2Notepad.csv
21/08/2014  07:15 PM               119 Tw2REPL.csv
```

C:\myfiles>file Tw2AWK.csv TwREPL.csv Tw2Notepad.csv

```
Tw2AWK.csv;     UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
Tw2REPL.csv;     UTF-8 Unicode text
Tw2Notepad.csv; UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

**HEX of these files is as follows**

C:\myfiles>xxd -p Tw2REPL.csv

```
0a222344656c686947616e675261706520776173206120736d616c6c2069
6e636964656e7420746f2023536d616c6c5261706973744a6169746c6579
20646e61696e6469612e636f6d2f696e6469612f7265706f72742d69e280
a6207069632e747769747465722e636f6d2f6762565070776637744f22
```

C:\myfiles>xxd -p Tw2AWK.csv

```
0d0a222344656c686947616e675261706520776173206120736d616c6c20
696e636964656e7420746f2023536d616c6c5261706973744a6169746c65
7920646e61696e6469612e636f6d2f696e6469612f7265706f72742d69e2
80a6207069632e747769747465722e636f6d2f6762565070776637744f22
0d0a
```

C:\myfiles>xxd -p Tw2Notepad.csv

```
efbbbf0d0a222344656c686947616e675261706520776173206120736d61
6c6c20696e636964656e7420746f2023536d616c6c5261706973744a6169
746c657920646e61696e6469612e636f6d2f696e6469612f7265706f7274
2d69e280a6207069632e747769747465722e636f6d2f6762565070776637
744f220d0a
```

**I want Tw2REPL.csv to look like Tw2Notepad.csv
How can I do it?**

**NOTE:** I have do this all via command line . I can use any 3rd party standalone  exe's though. I am on Windows XP

Please help, its very important for me

Answer (score 2):

First, add the bytes `ef bb bf` (UTF-8 encoded U+FEFF) to the beginning of the file. It's the byte-order mark, which was invented for UTF-16 and doesn't make much sense for UTF-8, though some programs rely on it.

```
$ (echo ef bb bf; xxd -p file.csv) | xxd -r -p > file.csv.new

C:\> (echo ef bb bf & xxd -p file.csv) | xxd -r -p > file.csv.new
```

Then, convert Unix line-endings (LF `0a`) to Windows format (CR LF `0d 0a`).

```
    $ unix2dos file.csv
or: $ todos file.csv
or: $ sed "s/$/\r/" file.csv > file.csv.new
```

Since you have `xxd`, I assume you also have Vim. You can do this in Vim by opening the file, then using:

```
:set bomb ff=dos
:w
```

Comment: Sorry sir for not clarifying, but i have to do all of this via commandline (i.e batch commands). I can use any 3rd party exe's like sed, tr, xxd, though. Thanks (P.s. i not not a (very) technical user)

Comment: @SuperUserMan: See edits.

Comment: dang, i forgot to tell, i am on windows xp  not linux :(

Comment: @SuperUserMan: The first command remains almost the same, just change the `;` to `&` if you use cmd.exe rather than sh/bash. The other tools (`todos` or `sed`) can be installed the same way you already installed the `file` or `xxd` commands.

Comment: @grawity curious, I notice that xxd -r -p gives a different result to xxd -rp.   http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iG5C0Jsw    -r -p seems to not be funny, though you used -rp

Comment: @barlop: Ah, maybe `-rp` is incorrect then; I just assumed it'd be the same.

Comment: @grawity for the record, that was tested in cygwin